Manhwa who start from the beginning
Just wanted to know the title of manhwa wherein the mc start again from the beginning. I mean, some people including the mc sudden got to some unknown place and there the first thing they need to do is to survive from some zombies. Btw, the mc is already strong and he likes to pretend that it is also his first time. He is also a calculative one 'cause he only supported those who he thinks will be useful to him. Thanks.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Memorize

Having been summoned to the alternate, game-like universe of the Whole Plane 10 years ago by mysterious angelic beings, Soohyun has finally reached the Apex of the world. But at what cost? Using his privilege as the Apex, Soohyun invokes the power of Code Zero to go back 10 years and rectify his past filled with tragedy.

Your description perfectly matches with the plot. Experienced mc goes back into the past (the point in time when he got transported into another world). He gathers useful comrades with potential and helps them survive the first mission.

